# Change IP of Secondary Storage on Cloudstack

Tags: apache-cloudstack

I want to change ip for secondary storage. Is it possible to change? If possible please show me the right place.

If cannot change ip please guide me how to delete it from UI and database.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide examples of what you're trying to do and what has not worked. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

What you will find easiest is to spin up a new SSVM and then migrate over to it. The migration process will involve some SQL - this [Citrix Knowledgebase answer](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX135229) will point you in the general direction of what needs to be done.